# the string str is always empty although it is filled with data from the.geojson file any idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, geojson

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#p1").load("reporting/data.geojson").toString();
      var str = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = str;
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <h2>try</h2>
  </div>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the code, p1 clearly shows on the screen but my actual problem is that i cant fill the string with it, "maybe the load function is the last to act i dont know" kinda new on this. I need to put the .geojson text in a string, or any other way to extract the coordinates would save me the trouble of string eddting. thank you iij advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the *callback* of `load` to get the data from `#p1`.

The `load` method is asynchronous, so the code does not wait for the data to load and executes the next statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#p1").load("reporting/data.geojson", function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = str;
  });
});
```

As you're using jQuery, you can use `html()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#p1").load("reporting/data.geojson", function () {
        $('#p2').html($('#p1').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution , but i solved the problem using the getJson function. then converted it to String. thank you